# Setting up ZeroMQ in a Visual Studio '13 Project

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, zeromq

I'm trying to get ZeroMQ to work with my C++ project. I want to do the ZeroMQ Hello World tutorial, shown below:

```
//  Hello World server
#include <zmq.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>

int main (void)
{
    //  Socket to talk to clients
    void *context = zmq_ctx_new ();
    void *responder = zmq_socket (context, ZMQ_REP);
    int rc = zmq_bind (responder, "tcp://*:5555");
    assert (rc == 0);

    while (1) {
        char buffer [10];
        zmq_recv (responder, buffer, 10, 0);
        printf ("Received Hello\n");
        sleep (1);          //  Do some 'work'
        zmq_send (responder, "World", 5, 0);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

However, whenever I try to compile and run it, Visual Studio says it can't find zmq.h or any of the ZeroMQ methods I am using. I already installed ZeroMQ from http://zeromq.org/distro:microsoft-windows, what else do I have to do to get it to work?

Comment: you have an error ; sleep(1); needs to be Sleep(1);

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Including the headers:

---

- Right click Project -> Properties -> C/C++ -> General
- Edit 'Additional Include Directories'
- Add C:\Program Files\ZeroMQ 4.0.4\include
- Right click 'Header Files' -> Add -> Existing Item -> C:\Program Files\ZeroMQ 4.0.4\include\zmq.h

Adding the library dir:

---

- Right click Project -> Properties -> Linker -> General
- Edit 'Additional Library Directories'
- Add C:\Program Files\ZeroMQ 4.0.4\lib\

Linking to the proper library:

---

- Right click Project -> Properties -> General
- Check "Platform Toolset", notice the version number (ex: **v120**)
- Configuration Properties -> Linker -> Input
- Edit 'Additional Dependencies'
- Add appopriate toolset library (ex: libzmq-**v120**-mt-gd-4_0_4.lib) "-gd-" is the debug version

Ensure your app is 64-bit

---

- Build -> Configuration Manager
- Active solution platform -> New...
- Select x64
- Copy settings from Win32
- Right click Project -> Properties -> Linker -> All Options
- Edit "Output File" set to ".\x64\Debug\whatever.exe"

Include the pre-compiled dll as a resource for distribution

---

- Right click Project -> Properties -> Build Events -> Post-Build Event
- Edit "Command Line"
- insert copy command

ex:

`copy /Y "C:\Program Files\ZeroMQ 4.0.4\bin\libzmq-v120-mt-gd-4_0_4.dll" "$(OutDir)"`

Answer (score 1):

You should [download and install](http://zeromq.org/area:download) 0MQ first.
Then you will be able to configure your Project properties to point to the right include and lib paths.